# Using tab layout without fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tabs

Is this possible or depreciated? In other words, can I tab between activities? Every resource I have looked for online has only ever mentioned fragments in relation to using tabs but this I doubt that the developers would force this on everyone. It should definitely be possible to still use a tab layout with activities right?

Answer (score 0):

No, usually activities fill whole screen. And now I think Single activity is officially recommended way (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU)

But you can use Tabs with custom views. There is library that helps building View-based Android applications (https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor)